# Cordova plugin media error al ejecutar multiples audios

Tags: ios, cordova, plugin

estoy desarrollando una apliacion con Cordova y AnuglarJS

Estoy utilizando el plugin Media de cordova, pero tengo un problema que no logro solucionar y solo me sucede en iOs, en otras plataformas funciona bien

Tengo un audio de fondo en loop, y otro audio al abrir un pop up que solo suena una vez.

Mientras ejecuto el audio de background si suena el otro audio, al finalizar este audio tambien se detiene el audio de background

Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Muchas gracias

EDIT:

```
backgroundMusic = new Media(path,
        function () {
            //success (object has completed the current play, record, or stop)
        },
        function (err) {
            //error
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err);
        },
        function (status) {
            //status, volvemos a lanzar el sonido si se para
            if(status == Media.MEDIA_STOPPED){
                //trapi para que en mobile el audio no se pare y haga bien el loop
                backgroundMusic.seekTo(1);
                backgroundMusic._position = 0;
                //hasta aqui el trapi
                backgroundMusic.play({playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked : false});
            }
        }
    );
```

creo el audio corto

```
if(openPopUp == undefined){
    openPopUp = new Media(pathPopUp,
        function () {
            //success (object has completed the current play, record, or stop)
        },
        function (err) {
            //error
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err);
        },
        function (status) {
            //status, volvemos a lanzar el sonido si se para
            if(status == Media.MEDIA_STOPPED){
                //trapi para que en mobile el audio no se pare y haga bien el loop
                openPopUp.seekTo(1);
                openPopUp._position = 0;
            }
        }
    );
}
```

ejecuto el audio de background

```
backgroundMusic.play({playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked : false});
```

luego tengo una funcion que ejecuta el audio de popup

```
$rootScope.$on("playOpenPopUp", function(){
    playOpenPopUp();
});
function playOpenPopUp(){
    openPopUp.play({playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked : false});
}
```

todo esto lo tengo en un controller, como se puede ver tenngo un listener en este controler que ejecuta el play del audio, otros controllers lanzan este evento para que este lo capture y haga el play

Comment: puedes dejar tu codigo, como reproduces tu audio en background y como el del popup?

Comment: @sioesi, he editado la pregunta, espero este todo lo que necesitabas

Comment: Estimado! Haz probado pausar el audio background mientras se ejecuta el segundo audio?

Comment: @sioesi SI lo pauso funciona ok, pero no es lo que pretendo, el segundo audio es un audio muy corto, de un segundo, en el juego queda extraño que pausar el audio de background y volver hacer el play

Comment: te lo preguntaba, porque creo que en iOS es distinto la reproduccion del audio que en otros S.O, creo que tu proyecto Ionic desde XCODE debes de dar un permiso o algo asi, voy a seguri averiguando!

Comment: gracias @sioesi ! me has dado un punto por donde seguir investigando, si encuentro alguna cosa lo comentare por aqui, igualmente agradeceria que si encuentras cualquier cosa la comentes

Comment: @siosi parece que es un error propio del plugin de Cordova:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7599
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11026

Comment: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/media/ mira, en la primera parte explica que pasa con ios, con sonidos en background! echale un vistazo!

Comment: @sioesi gracias! Yoe stasva consultando esta pagina
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media/
Y no encontraba nada, le doy un vistazo a tu link